# Bind Button to start other Activity on Mvvmcross

Tags: button, binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

first i use Xamarin, visual Studio and Mvvmcross.

on one of my Tabs are 3 Buttons. Everyone starts a new Activity. My question is how i have to bind this Buttons and more interesting is the question how the command look to start a new Activity. My problem is not the Binding of the Button to a Comand. its how can i start a other Activity from the ViewModel.

i can Binding a Button to a Command like Save data ore some thing. but all thinks that use on the "Buisnesslayer"

thx and Greets

Comment: Please show what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view model you would have your ICommand like so:

```
public ICommand GoSimpleCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<SimpleViewModel>()); }
    }
```

See navigation example [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Navigation/Navigation.Core).